# Dropdown list data not match using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

First of all thank you guys for helping me for this little problem I have.

Straight to the matters, but first of all I've been looking about this scripts by googling it and of course in this forum.

My Database:

(1). tbl_barang >

id_barang
id_kategori
id_klasifikasi
nama_barang

(2). tbl_kategori >

id_kategori
nama_kategori

(3). tbl_klasifikasi >

id_klasifikasi
nama_klasifikasi

And here my scripts >

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function showBarang(katid) {
        document.frm.submit();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="frm" id="frm">
<table width="500" border="0">

<!--Kategori-->
  <tr>
    <td width="119">Kategori</td>
    <td width="371">
       <select name="id_kategori" id="id_kategori" onChange="showBarang(this.value);">
       <option value="">--Select--</option>
       <?php
        $sql1="select * from tbl_kategori";
       $sql_row1=mysql_query($sql1);
       while($sql_res1=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_row1))
       {
       ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $sql_res1["id_kategori"]; ?>" <?php if($sql_res1["id_kategori"]==$_REQUEST["id_kategori"]) { echo "Selected"; } ?>><?php echo $sql_res1["nama_kategori"]; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
       </select>
       </td>
  </tr>
 <!-- Klasifikasi -->
 <tr>
    <td>Klasifikasi</td>
    <td id="td_company">
       <select name="id_klasifikasi" id="id_klasifikasi" onChange="showBarang(this.value);">
       <option value="">--Select--</option>
       <?php
        $sql1="select * from tbl_klasifikasi";
       $sql_row1=mysql_query($sql1);
       while($sql_res1=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_row1))
       {
       ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $sql_res1["id_klasifikasi"]; ?>" <?php if($sql_res1["id_klasifikasi"]==$_REQUEST["id_klasifikasi"]) { echo "Selected"; } ?>><?php echo $sql_res1["nama_klasifikasi"]; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
       </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nama Barang</td>
    <td id="td_company">
       <select name="id_barang" id="id_barang">

       <option value="">--Select--</option>
       <?php
       $sql="select * from tbl_barang where id_kategori and id_klasifikasi='$_REQUEST[id_kategori] && [id_klasifikasi]'";
       $sql_row=mysql_query($sql);
       while($sql_res=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_row))
       {
       ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $sql_res["id_barang"]; ?>"><?php echo $sql_res["nama_barang"]; ?></option>
       <?php
       }
       ?>
    </select>
       </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, when we choose kategori and choose klasifikasi the data 'nama_barang' should displays on the third dropdown list. But it's all mess, I don't know how to request two id's from the different tables and display it from one table 'tbl_barang'.

The short issue is, I don't know how to display the data from tbl_barang > 'nama_barang' that have related id's from 'tbl_kategori' and 'tbl_klasifikasi'.

Thank you so much if someone here help me, it's been three days and I'm stuck.

Thank you and best regards,

Kris

Comment: Why the wierd stuff with field and field ='something && other' ?  why not WHERE id_kategori=".($_REQUEST['id_kategori']+0)." AND  id_klasifikasi=".($_REQUEST['id_klasifikasi']+0)  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do a [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) between different tables.

Next point is your sql syntax:

```
$sql="select * from tbl_barang where id_kategori and id_klasifikasi='$_REQUEST[id_kategori] && [id_klasifikasi]'";
```

Try this one:

```
$sql="select * from tbl_barang where id_kategori = ".$_REQUEST[id_kategori]." and id_klasifikasi = ".$_REQUEST[id_klasifikasi].";";
```

When those ids are stored as numbers do not use quotation marks to wrap them.

Hope it helps. It is not really clear what is you problem.

Comment: @Kris when the answer was the solution than please mark it as the correct answer :)